# Why does my certificate provider ask me to disable its root certificate?

Tags: security, security-certificate

I received an SSL certificate from GoDaddy yesterday and [their instructions](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/4801) to install the certificate seemed weird. To be precise, they asked me to disable their root certificate in server.

> NOTE: If the Go Daddy® Class 2 Certification Authority root certificate is currently installed on your machine, you need to disable it from the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder.

What do I need to disable the root certificate?

Another question: they asked me to put intermediate certificates on the server. I can sure do that on **server** but my **clients** might not have them. Does it matter?

Comment: Has Mike answered your question or do you need more answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer your second question: The clients will get the intermediate certificates from your server (assuming you install them properly), so they **will** be able to use them to authenticate your SSL certificate against the root certificate.

Comment: So these intermediate certificates are automatically downloaded by clients during SSL negotiation. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.